# How to conditionally apply a 'where' condition only when there is an entry exists

Tags: sql, select, join

I want to create a temp table base on 3 other tables. But there is a condition may or may not apply depending on if there is an entry exists in 3rd table. How can I insert the different cases in a 'where' condition?

```
select table1.tran_num, table2.impact
from table 1, table2, table3
where tables1.tran_num = 12345
and table1.index = table2.index
"and case when table2.index in table3.index then table2.version = table3.version"
```

Comment: Try it creating another Select for your 3rd table and, using operators, either it is created or not. 
And, since you're constructing an 3rd table based on 3 others, is a view not an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `INNER JOIN`

```
select  table1.tran_num, table2.impact
from    table1 
        INNER JOIN table2
            ON table1.index = table2.index
        INNER JOIN table3
            ON table2.version = table3.version
where   tables1.tran_num = 12345
```

the query above will only show records if all records are present in all tables. But if you want a record still to be shown even if column `version` of `table2` is not present on `table3`, then a `LEFT JOIN` is required.

```
select  table1.tran_num, table2.impact
from    table1 
        INNER JOIN table2
            ON table1.index = table2.index
        LEFT JOIN table3
            ON table2.version = table3.version
where   tables1.tran_num = 12345
```

To learn more about join, please see the article below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: If I saw ur answer or if at least knew u r around, I wouldn't post ;-) my concept is totally based on `exists` as I didn't see any query from the OP. Let alone was thinking he is trying to insert data based on  exist. Things can be simple reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join and a where clause similar to

```
where joined_table.id is null or joined_table.filter_col in (1,2,3)
```

For example:

```
select t1.id, t2.id
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
 on t1.fk_id = t2.id
where t2.id is null or t2.filter_col in (1,2,3,4)
```

The above query will get all records from t1 that are NOT on t2, or records from t1 which ARE on t2 and their equivalente filter_col on t2 is in (1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following logic:

```
 IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
 FROM tablea a Left JOIN tableb b 
ON a._id = b._id 
Left JOIN tablec c ON b._id = c._id 
 SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```